# Многопоточность, перемещение шариков

Tags: c#

необходимо сделать приложение перемещения шариков по форме на произвольную точку,при создании 2 потоков, шарики отрисовываются,но при запуске таймера ,потоки прекращаются, всё пропадает.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static Graphics graphics;
    Thread th1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Print));
    Thread th2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Print));
    static public int x, y;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        
    }
    
    static void Print()
    {
        Drawer();           
    }
    static void Drawer()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        x += rnd.Next(-10, 10);
        y += rnd.Next(-10, 10);
        if ((x >= 300) || (y >= 300) || (x <= 0) || (y <= 0))
        {
            x = rnd.Next(0, 300);
            y = rnd.Next(0, 300);
        }
        Invalidate();

    }


   

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        x = rnd.Next(0, 300);
        y = rnd.Next(0, 300);
        graphics = ActiveForm.CreateGraphics();
        graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, x, y, 10, 10);
    }

   
    

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       th1.Start();         
       th2.Start();
       th1.Join();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Если у вас есть таймер, то зачем потоки? Если есть потоки, то зачем таймер?

Comment: `ActiveForm.CreateGraphics()` - никогда, никогда так не делайте! Рисовать нужно в событии `Paint`, графикс брать из его аргументов.

Comment: Приведите код в порядок: уберите пустые строки и неиспользуемый `Form1_Load`. Вы в Блокноте код пишете? Visual Studio подсказывает же, где и что можно исправить.

Comment: `graphics = ActiveForm.CreateGraphics();` - за это минус. Используйте `e.Graphics`!

Comment: Я для чего писал ответ с подробными объяснениями? Вы его совсем не читали? Зачем в каждом методе создаёте `Random`?

Comment: И посмотрите в словаре перевод слова Drawer. :)

Answer (score 2):

У вас тут сразу несколько проблем.

```
th1.Start(); // старт потока 1
th1.Join();  // ждём завершения потока 1
th2.Start(); // старт потока 2
```

Вы запустили поток 1 и тут же ждёте, когда он закончится. И только после этого запускаете поток 2 и не ждёте его завершения. Это точно тот сценарий, который вы планировали?

```
static public int x, y;
```

Вы обращаетесь к этим переменным из нескольких потоков сразу, читаете их и пишете. При этом не используете никакой синхронизации (например `lock`). Это рано или поздно кончится какой-то проблемой, когда в переменных будет лежать непонятно что в результате того, что разные потоки одновременно в переменную что-то запишут и непонятно что прочитают.

Вы работаете с `GUI` не только из основного потока, это может привести к вылету/зависанию программы. Нужно использовать `Invoke` или ещё каким-то образом делать так, чтобы с `GUI` работал только основной поток программы. Нормальная парадигма - это когда обновляет `GUI` одна функция, которая периодически запускается, а дополнительные потоки только изменяют состояние программы, каким-то образом готовят данные для отрисовки той функцией, но сами рисовкой не занимаются.

Comment: `this.Invoke((Action)(() => Drawer()));`

Comment: @aepot Да, можно так, но в целом - хорошо ли это, правильно ли архитектурно так делать? )

Answer (score 1):

Вы вручную создаёте экземпляр `Graphics`:

```
graphics = ActiveForm.CreateGraphics();
```

Никогда так не делайте! Рисовать можно только в событии `Paint`, графикс брать из его аргументов.

---

В событии `Timer_Tick` вы создаёте новый экземпляр класса `Random`. Не следует так делать. Лучше создать его один раз (скажем в конструкторе или событии `Load` формы) и сделать полем формы.

---

Когда вызывается метод `Invalidate`, это приводит к перерисовке формы - вызову события `Paint`. Если в обработчике этого события вы не отрисовываете заново шарики, то неудивительно, что они пропадают.

---

В потоках нужно запускать только "тяжёлый" код, который долго выполняется. Сейчас у вас в методе `Drawer` выполняется всего несколько строк, что быстро. Поэтому смысла от запуска потоков нет.

---

---

Я набросал пример, в котором анимируется движения нескольких шариков.
Потоки не используются, потому что таймера вполне достаточно.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormAppDraw
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Timer timer;

        private Random rnd = new Random();

        private List<Ball> balls = new List<Ball>();

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            Size = new Size(400, 400);

            this.Load += Form1_Load;
            this.Paint += Form1_Paint;

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            balls.Add(new Ball { X = rnd.Next(0, 300), Y = rnd.Next(0, 300), Brush = Brushes.Red });
            balls.Add(new Ball { X = rnd.Next(0, 300), Y = rnd.Next(0, 300), Brush = Brushes.Green });
            balls.Add(new Ball { X = rnd.Next(0, 300), Y = rnd.Next(0, 300), Brush = Brushes.Blue });

            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var ball in balls)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(ball.Brush, ball.X, ball.Y, 10, 10);
            }
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var ball in balls)
            {
                ball.X += rnd.Next(-10, 10);
                ball.Y += rnd.Next(-10, 10);

                if ((ball.X >= 300) || (ball.Y >= 300) || (ball.X <= 0) || (ball.Y <= 0))
                {
                    ball.X = rnd.Next(0, 300);
                    ball.Y = rnd.Next(0, 300);
                }
            }

            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    class Ball
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public Brush Brush { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Класс Ball следует разместить в отдельном файле.

Comment: Необходимо использовать именно потоки, по заданию)

Comment: @ЖеняЕрмолаев - попробуйте переписать свой код с применением потоков, но полностью убрав таймер. Покажите новую попытку решения, отредактировав вопрос. Мы поправим, что не получилось. Напоминаю: уберите таймер совсем.

Comment: изменил, но всё равно не понимаю как правильно это реализовать с помощью потоков..