# Нужно включить многопоточность в проекте winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно включить Thread, дабы отрисовывающиеся облака не зависели от остальных частей, но в каком месте это сделать - не понимаю. Код с облаками ниже.

```
class Cloud
{
    static int n = 30, num = 0;
    int[] D = new int[n], 
          X = new int[n],
          Y = new int[n];
    Random rand;
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
    Brush br = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
    public void DrawCloud(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(br, X[i], Y[i], D[i], D[i]);
            X[i] += 1;
            if (X[0] > 850) newCloud();
        }
    }
    public Cloud(Random r, int n)
    {
        num = n;
        rand = r;
        newCloud();
    }
    private void newCloud()
    {
        D[0] = 30; X[0] = -rand.Next(40, 200) * num; Y[0] = rand.Next(130, 150);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            D[i] = rand.Next(D[0] - 10, D[0] + 10);
            X[i] = rand.Next(X[0] - 50, X[0] + 50);
            Y[i] = rand.Next(Y[0] - 10, Y[0] + 15);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Конкретное окно для отрисовки может использовать только один поток - тот, в котором это окно было создано.  Так что многопоточность с отрисовкой вам не поможет.

Comment: Используйте поток в том месте, где вызываете метод `DrawCloud`. P.S. winforms способна отрисовывать сотни кадров в секунду. Имхо, нет необходимости что-то выносить в поток.

Comment: Зацените: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1268194/184217 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278921/184217

Comment: Как этот код запустить, чтобы увидеть как он тормозит? Дополните вопрос, мне пока непонятно, чем помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Генерируйте облака в другом потоке(Thread, Task, Parallel), а уже при отрисовке вызывайте YourForm.Invoke(() => Draw());

В это примере это даже не нужно, ибо взаимодействие происходит в главном UI потоке.

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
new Thread(() =>
{
    g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue), new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200));
}).Start();
```

Comment: Что такое `this` в данном конкретном случае? Если это `Image/Bitmap`, то так делать можно. А если это GUI-контрол - форма, панель, пикчабокс, - то так делать нельзя.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, форма. Я проверил, у меня работает